# How can i add many elements to a listbox from a single layout?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I am new to python. I want to add many elements on a listbox using a for-loop. The problem is that only the last one is showing and if I have to add multiple elements I have to do it manually

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,end,stam,phys):
        self.name = name
        self.end = end
        self.stam = stam
        self.phys = phys
def make_player(name,end,stam,phys):
    player = Player(name,end,stam,phys)
    return player

#Get the data from the cells

AllPlayers = []

for i in range(1, sheet1.nrows):
    name = sheet1.cell_value(i, 0)
    end = sheet1.cell_value(i, 1)
    stam = sheet1.cell_value(i, 2)
    phys = sheet1.cell_value(i, 3)
    currentPlayer = make_player(name,end,stam,phys)
    AllPlayers.append(currentPlayer)
    print(currentPlayer.end)
```

And here is the layout :

```
Readlayout = [
    [sg.Text('Chose from list')],
    [sg.Text('Name,Endurance,Stamina,Physical')],
    [sg.Listbox([currentPlayer.name],size=(40,20),key='Players')],
    [sg.Button('Ok')],
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[currentPlayer.name]` is a list with only one player's name.
To get the names for all players, maybe you can do it like

```py
[player.name for player in AllPlayers]
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much. Never crossed my mind i can do the for inside the brackets.